# Should I be opening the same file multiple times throughout my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Should I be opening the same file multiple times throughout my program? Or should I read the file in once to a data structure and then pass the data structure to my different functions?

To be clear, I am not asking about opening multiple instances of the file at the same time. But at different points during the program.

For example, I have dumped a nested dictionary to a json file that stores user info.

```
    {
    "user1": {
        "email": "user1@somewhere.com", 
        "first_name": "John", 
        "last_name": "Doe"}, 
    "user2": {
        "email": "user2@somewhere.com", 
        "first_name": "Jane", 
        "last_name": "Doe"}
}
```

Right now, I have functions to display all user data. Which reads in the file and prints the info. Then I also have a search function that allows me to search for a username and display only that user's info, for that I also have to read in the file. Furthermore, I have function to update user info, which, you guessed it, opens the file and then rewrites it.

It seems clunky and redundant to do it this way. It seems it would be better have a function that reads in the file and returns the data structure and then I just pass that around. Such as:

```
def get_data():
    with open("data.json", 'r') as fin:
        return json.load(fin)
```

However, I am not sure what the best practice is.

Comment: I'd say it depend. Can the file be externally modified? Are you limited in memory or more concerned about performance?

Comment: Adding to the previous questions by @JordanBrière: Do you need concurrent access to that data? My recommendation would be to use a sqlite db instead or some other kind of lightweight database.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just concerned with performance and clean code of course ;) the json file isn't huge. I just have about 50 "users" in the file.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have stated that this is just a little project I am working on. Trying to get back into using python. So, no concurrent access is needed.

Comment: Then parse it once so it will be faster to access.